# Error in creating website on GITHUB PAGES

Tags: html, css, github, bootstrap-4, github-pages

[image]

I have made my project with bootstrap, html and css. But the Github pages are only showing the readme file and sending me the error mail. Please help me, this project is important for me

Comment: The email you posted a screencap says that the build was successful. The error email is a suggestion about the kind of files you have added to version control and is not related to your problem (see the PS in @subhalingam-d's answer for the solution). Also your question doesn't include any information from which to answer the question, such as a link to your github repo and a link to your repo's github page URL. See here for more information: https://guides.github.com/features/pages/

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, `index.html` is missing from your repository.**

If you have used only Bootstrap, CSS, and HTML, you probably don't even need npm. You can just upload your files (including those folders for images and CSS) and then go to your Repository Settings and in Github Pages, set the source. If you have an `index.html`, then `<username>.github.io/repo-name` will render it automatically after a successful build.

You might find [this](https://github.com/subhalingamd/subhalingamd.github.io) repository which was made using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap (and Javascript) helpful to refer to.

PS: Don't push `node_modules` on GitHub. You should ideally add that folder to `.gitignore`. These modules can be installed by the user who clones your repo using `npm` commands.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your query @vishesh? If so consider accepting this answer :)